# How to get alphabates letter number and operate on it

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

I have a requirement where I need to return the alphabet when given an alphabet and a number. 
Example if given, C and 4 I will return C+4 = G 
Also if given C and -2 I will return C + (-2) = A

If I have AA then, AA + 4 =  AD, So I will always want to take the last character from the string.

I was thinking of using string array to store alphabets, but it seems kind of bad solution. Is there any way by which I can get it done better ?

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you saying you want to get some function `foo(char c, int i)` that returns `'G'` for `foo('C', 4)`?  If so, that's just `c + i`.

Comment: What would be result of `A` and `-2`?

Comment: Looks like you don't need to store the whole alphabet, but only one letter?! Can the mathematical expressions be more complicated than `<letter> + <number>`? In general, since you want to do maths, you have to make sure that eventually your letters are converted to numbers, or else you won't be able to add them.

Comment: Check question again everyone please. Before downvoting.

Comment: What would be result of `AZ` and `+1`? Would it be `BA` or `AA` or maybe something else (exception for example)?

Comment: AZ + 1 = BA if I am not wrong, I am dealing with excel columns here. to make it more specific

Comment: @Downvoters, please rethink after my edited question.

Comment: `Z` + 1 = `AA` or `A` (overflow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alphabet characters are all already in order, all you need to do is add a number to one to get another.

I presume you want something like this:

```
addToChar('A', 4);

char addToChar(char inChar, int inNum)
{
  return (char)(inChar + inNum);
}
```

You may want to check whether it is less than 'A' or greater than 'Z' as well.

**In response to your edit:**

```
void addToChar(char[] inChars, int inNum)
{
   for (int i = inChars.length-1; inNum != 0 && i >= 0; i--)
   {
      int result = inChars[i]-'A'+inNum;
      if (result >= 0)
      {
         inNum = result / 26;
         result %= 26;
      }
      else
      {
         inNum = 0;
         while (result < 0) // there may be some room for optimization here
         {
            result += 26;
            inNum--;
         }
      }
      inChars[i] = (char)('A'+result);
   }
}
```

**To deal with overflow:** (somewhat less efficient) (`'Z' + 1` outputs `'AA'`)

```
static String addToChar(String inChars, int inNum)
{
   String output = "";
   for (int i = inChars.length()-1; inNum != 0 || i >= 0; i--)
   {
      if (i < 0 && inNum < 0)
         return "Invalid input";
      int result = i >= 0 ? inChars.charAt(i)-'A'+inNum
                          : -1+inNum;
      if (result > 0)
      {
         inNum = result / 26;
         result %= 26;
      }
      else
      {
         inNum = 0;
         while (result < 0)
         {
            result += 26;
            inNum--;
         }
      }
      output = (char)('A'+result) + output;
   }
   return output;
}
```

Comment: @WarriorPrince Edited again (to properly deal with negative input).

Comment: @WarriorPrince Edited again (to deal with overflow).

Answer (score 1):

try this for example :

```
public class example {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     int number = 2;
     char example = 'c';

     System.out.println((char)(example+number));

    }
 }
```

Comment: Check question again. Edited

Comment: Ive added another answer updated with the new question

Answer (score 1):

this is an example for the updated question :

still need to verify the input number and input String (lets say what happens if the number is 124 ?)

```
 public class example {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     int number = 1;
     String example = "nicd";
     //get the last letter from the string
     char lastChar = example.charAt(example.length()-1);
     //add the number to the last char and save it
     lastChar = (char) (lastChar+number);
     //remove the last letter from the string
     example = example.substring(0, example.length()-1);
     //add the new letter to the end of the string
     example = example.concat(String.valueOf(lastChar));
     //will print nice
     System.out.println(example);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store alphabet letters in an array; this is one reason why ASCII has all letters in consecutive order.

Perform the math operation, which implicitly converts the `char` to an `int`, then cast the result to a `char`.  You'll have to check that you don't go before 'A' or after 'Z'.

Here's an [ASCII table reference](http://www.asciitable.com/.).

Comment: You're right; I've edited my answer.

Comment: Including a [Unicode reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF) may be more correct, since this is what Java uses.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever google about character set? Like ASCII, a character is already represented by a number.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your character to an `int` with a cast, then add your `int`, and convert it back to a `char`. For instance:

```
char c = 'c';
int cInt = (int)c;
int gInt = cInt + 4;
char g = (char)gInt; // 'G'
```